# Select :even <br> tags within a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using the following code to hide every other < br > but I need to figure out how to hide every other < br > only within a div, not my entire page. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<script>
    $("br:even").css("display", "none");
</script>
```

Comment: please share your html... does the div has an id or class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the div first then use the [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find `br` elements within it

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        $('divselector').find("br:even").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    Before break 1
    <br/>
    Before break 2
    <br/>
    Before break 3
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="two">
    Before break 4
    <br/>
    Before break 5
    <br/>
    Before break 6
    <br/>
</div>
```

Then you can select the first DIV (`one`), then hide the even DIVs, like this:

```
$("#one br:even").css("display", "none");
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQLCq/).